# Is it possible to chain function calls in PHP?

Tags: php

If I have this functions

```
function function1 ( $myParameter ) {
...
}

function function2 ( $myParameter ) {
...
}

function function3 ( $myParameter ) {
...
}
```

When I call

```
function1( function2( function3( $myParameter ) ) )
```

I would like to call like this:

```
function3( $myParameter ) -> function2() -> function1()
```

function3( $myParameter ) is sent as parameter to function2()

A PHP plugin exists (or something else) ?

Thx

Comment: You want the result of your function to be passed for the next function ? Or a reference to the function to be passed ?

Comment: @cyrbil He wants the second syntax to do what the first syntax does.

Comment: `->` is used for calling methods of objects. I'm not aware of anything that would change it to do functions like this.

Comment: It is possible to have the second syntax (see "fluent interface", "method chaining"), but it is *not* equivalent to the first. It can be made to do similar things in the end though.

Comment: There is no php plugin to update the php parsing engine ? :(

Comment: @Barmar: The line `function3( $myParameter ) is sent as parameter to function2()`  made me tough that OP wants to pass function reference..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chained objects methods by returning an instance (with `$this`)
Here is a trivial example.

```
class foo {
    function function1() {
        echo "I'm function1\n";
        return $this;
    }
    function function2() {
        echo "I'm function2\n";
        return $this;
    }
    function function3() {
        echo "I'm function3\n";
        return $this;
    }
}


$bar = new foo();
$bar->function3()->function2()->function1();
```

Comment: To clarify your problem. When you want `function3( $myParameter ) -> function2() -> function1()`,  what *function3* need to return is an object with a method *function2* (etc for *function2* with *function1*).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by setting up the functions on an object. Since I don't know the domain it's hard to say how sane this is, however if it's just the code formatting you're interested in. you could use this.

```
<?php

class Functions
{
    protected $value;

    public function function1($param)
    {
        //do something
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function function2($param)
    {
        // do something to $this->value 
        return $this;
    }

    public function function3($param)
    {
        // do something to $this->value
        return $this;
    }
}

$class = new Functions();
$param = 'someVariable';

$result = $class->function3($param)->function2($param)->function1($param);
```

Again without knowing the domain it's hard to know how sensible this approach is